# Find a specific string between 2 strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

This is for Notepad++. I am trying to Find a word between two words; and if found, mark the whole thing.

```
    <lootgroup name="Random1" count="1">
      <item group="filler"/>
      <item group="filler"/>
    </lootgroup>

    <lootgroup name="Random2" count="1">
      <item group="filler"/>
      <item group="schematics"/>
      <item group="filler"/>
    </lootgroup>

    <lootgroup name="Random2" count="1">
      <item group="filler"/>
      <item group="schematics"/>
      <item group="filler"/>
      <item group="schematics"/>
    </lootgroup>
```

So I want to Find **"schematics"** between `<lootgroup`   and   `</lootgroup>`; and if found, mark/select all lines including `<lootgroup`   and   `</lootgroup>`.

I know about `<lootgroup(.*?)</lootgroup>` will select everything in between but I cannot figure out what to replace `(.*?)` with to match only if schematics is present between the two.

Number of "Item Groups" varies and "Item Group" is not always the name. That's why I'm searching for "schematic".

Using Notepad++ Find and Mark function.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Will this code work for you? `^\s*<lootgroup(.*\n.*){0,2}schem[\S\s]+?group>`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: It do for me ... copy it correctly,  and turn on regular expression switch ..

Comment: What do you mean by "mark ... all lines". Notepad++ has a specific meaning for the concept of  marking or marked lines.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Find what: `<lootgroup (?:(?!</lootgroup>).)+\bschematics\b(?:(?!</lootgroup>).)+</lootgroup>`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Mark All</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<lootgroup                  # opening tag
(?:(?!</lootgroup>).)+      # Tempered greedy token, make sure we don't encounter closing tag
\bschematics\b              # literally
(?:(?!</lootgroup>).)+      # Tempered greedy token, make sure we don't encounter closing tag
</lootgroup>                # closing tag
```

**Screenshot:**

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me ....

Find:`^\s*<loot(.*\n.*){0,2}schem[\S\s]+?group>`

Replace with:`nothing`

[image]